# Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10: Permission denied

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions

I have a computer with a 500gb SSD. In a 100GB partition, I have installed Windows 10 and it boots fine. I am now trying to install Ubuntu 19.0.4 in dual boot. I have tried many different options but the installation always stops at keyboard layout selection. Here is what I have done:

- Shrunk windows partition
- Created a new partition for Ubuntu
- Tried to install Ubuntu but it freezes at layout selection
- Tried to install the non-graphic installation, also freezes
- Tried to launch gparted from live USB but it freezes
- Tried to install 18.0.4, same issue.
- Checked that windows was not on dynamic partitions, and it's not.
- Managed to open gnome disks and format the partition in ext4
- Partition mounts in Ubuntu Live USB but still can't install
- When I run "fdisks -l" I see the partitions, but with "permission denied"

What should I do? I feel like I have exhausted my options.

Update: I formatted the drive and reinstalled Windows 10, still the same issue.

Comment: Related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176906/problem-installing-ubuntu-19-04-18-04

Comment: Seems like they didn't find a solution.

Comment: No, I placed a bounty on the question, but I am afraid there is no easy solution. Is your MB Asus too?

Comment: No it is HP. I managed to install Ubuntu on it without Windows, though. What I can't do is the dual boot. And I tried with several versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: When you installed Windows, did you use dynamic partitions in Windows? If so, don't do that.

Comment: No dynamic partitions, no. Let me update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out the issue. Not sure if this will be helpful to others but you never know. I had installed a PCI extension card so that I could connect more hard drives to my server. I didn't think I needed to remove it to install Windows and Ubuntu again, but turns out I do. Now it all works well and gparted can do its job. Thanks for your help everyone!