# How I solve problem of freezing system after entering password?

Tags: 18.04, freeze

Hello Ubuntu community,

I have Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on a Asus ZenBook UX303LB and face a seeming system freeze directly after entering my user password. The password dialog disappears thus only the purple background of the login page together with my mouse pointer remain visible. This problem does not occur if *Ubuntu with Wayland* is selected before logging in.

I opened the TTY3 during seeming system freeze and get the following messages repeating over and over again.

```
[3434.281062] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_writepages: jbd2_start: 13312 pages, ino 262223; err-30
[...] systemd-journald[328]: Failed to write entry (21 items, 604 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
```

Output of df -h is as follows:

```
Dateisystem    Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
udev            3,9G       0  3,9G    0% /dev
tmpfs           787M    2,1M  785M    1% /run
/dev/sda7        28G     18G  8,8G   67% /
tmpfs           3,9G       0  3,9G    0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M    4,0K  5,0M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G       0  3,9G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1      1,0M    1,0M     0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/93
/dev/loop2      384K    384K     0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/550
/dev/loop3      114M    114M     0  100% /snap/blender-tpaw/3
/dev/loop4      162M    162M     0  100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
/dev/loop5      256K    256K     0  100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/5
/dev/loop6      1,0M    1,0M     0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/100
/dev/loop7      114M    114M     0  100% /snap/audacity/666
/dev/loop9      141M    141M     0  100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/100
/dev/loop8      2,5M    2,5M     0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/730
/dev/loop0       78M     78M     0  100% /snap/viking-gps/18
/dev/loop11     256M    256M     0  100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop10     384K    384K     0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/539
/dev/sda6       1,9G    170M  1,6G   10% /boot
/dev/loop12      55M     55M     0  100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/sda3        96M     31M   66M   32% /boot/efi
/dev/loop13     2,3M    2,3M     0  100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/145
/dev/loop14     106M    106M     0  100% /snap/audacity/648
/dev/loop16      63M     63M     0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop15      49M     49M     0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1474
/dev/loop17      55M     55M     0  100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop18     256M    256M     0  100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/33
/dev/sda8       125G    114G  4,8G   96% /home
/dev/loop20      94M     94M     0  100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/loop19     256K    256K     0  100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/9
/dev/loop21      98M     98M     0  100% /snap/core/9289
/dev/loop22     161M    161M     0  100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop23     141M    141M     0  100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98
/dev/loop24     182M    182M     0  100% /snap/spotify/36
/dev/loop25     2,5M    2,5M     0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/748
/dev/loop26     164M    164M     0  100% /snap/spotify/41
/dev/loop27     2,3M    2,3M     0  100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
tmpfs           787M     16K  787M    1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           787M    1,4M  786M    1% /run/user/1000
```

Removing .cache folder and using  `sudo apt clean`  together with executing `sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/sda7` made the file system error messages disappear. Unfortunately the seeming system freeze remains.
The login using TTY seems to work. May the fact that Ubuntu works fine when selecting *Ubuntu with Wayland* be a hint for the problems origin? Are  there logs I can provide to make the solution finding process easier?

Comment: And what do you have on /dev/sda7 ? Please update your question with the output of `df -h`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "sudo: unable to open ... Read-only file system"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197459/how-to-fix-sudo-unable-to-open-read-only-file-system)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem installing Ubuntu 19.04 (18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176906/problem-installing-ubuntu-19-04-18-04) in order to boot into Recovery mode and run the fsck program.

Comment: The linked article have helped to solve the systemd-journal error messages. However, the freeze is still unsolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change from nvidia-driver-440 back to X.Org X server has solved the issue although this doesn't explain why the graphic driver caused the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following steps:

1. Clear your .cache file
2. Clear your /var/cache directory
3. Reboot

and check free space available to you.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn’t solve the issue.